# Right way to declare typescript definitions for window

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define new types in the window object like `webkitAudioContext`. I've created a separate file called **window.d.ts** and inside that I've added the below code,

```
interface Window {
    AudioContext: Constructable;
    webkitAudioContext: Constructable;
}

interface Constructable {
    new();
}
```

From another module I'm importing the definition file as below,

```
/// <reference path="./window.d.ts" />

let contextClass = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let context = new contextClass();
```

The above two lines works just fine.

If I change the defintion file as below,

```
declare module window {
   export interface Window {
        AudioContext: Constructable;
        webkitAudioContext: Constructable;
    }

    interface Constructable {
        new();
    }
}
```

Then it's not working. What is the right way to define definitions to window?

Comment: I don't think you can put the window declaration inside a namespace, it would no longer match the type of the Window type provided by default.

Answer (score 2):

There is already exist community written definitions for `AudioContext` and `webkitAudioContext` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webaudioapi).
If you are not familiar with @types - you can read more aboit it [here](http://definitelytyped.org/), shortly - it contains a lot of definitions for a lot of libraries (you even may use `JQueryPromise` as a type).
Also there is [good practice](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/globals.html) of creating `global.d.ts` file with your custom definions, which'll contain code like this:

```
declare var myCustomLib: any;
```

Then you should add `global.d.ts` to `tsconfig.json`, so compiler will be aware of your definitions:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "./build"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "files": ["./src/globals"]
}
```

And if you are facing situations when you trying to access deprecated features you can access to them by `(... as any)` construction, like this:

```
let Ctx = window.AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext;
```

I hope some of this techniques will help you.